# How to get rid of instanceof in this Builder implementation

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, instanceof

### The idea

I need to create Commands. Commands can be configured with parameters.
Not every command can receive the same parameters. So some have to be ignored.

I have an abstract class Command in which I've defined a Builder. By default every append parameter throws 'UnsupportedOperationException'

```
public abstract class Command {

   public static abstract class CommandBuilder {

        // TODO instanceof. How to do this better?
        public CommandBuilder append(Parameter p)
            throws UnsupportedOperationException {

            if (p instanceof URLParameter)
                return append((URLParameter) p);

            if (p instanceof ActionParameter)
                return append((ActionParameter) p);

            if (p instanceof RepeatParameter)
                return append((RepeatParameter) p);

            if (p instanceof TimeOutParameter)
                return append((TimeOutParameter) p);

            return this;

        }

        public CommandBuilder append(URLParameter p)
                throws UnsupportedOperationException {

                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                        "URLParameter not applicable");

        }

        public CommandBuilder append(RepeatParameter p)
            throws UnsupportedOperationException {

                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "RepeatParameter not applicable");

            }
            ...

}
```

If you want a parameter to be applicable onto a certain concrete Command, lets say an FTPCommand.

You will have to do something like this:

```
public class FTPCommand extends Command {

    public static class Builder extends CommandBuilder {

    @Override
    public CommandBuilder append(URLParameter p) {
            System.out.println("URLParemeter appended");
                return this;
            }
        }

}
```

So that when a URLParameter is provided it doesn't throw an exception anymore but instead applies it.

But the client of this CommandBuilder might not be able to provide the concrete subclass. So in general a "Parameter" is given. But it needs to go to the right place (method)

Like a URLParameter must arrive at the `append(UrlParameter p)`

How can I do this in a clean(er) and nice(r) way? Because I'm not really 'enthousiastic' to use instanceof .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a classic [double-dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) or [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) scenario. From the double-dispatch reference:

> a mechanism that dispatches a function call to different concrete
>   functions depending on the runtime types of two objects involved in
>   the call

The `Parameter` and the `CommandBuilder` need to interact between themselves on what to do.

The `CommandBuilder` can call back on the parameter. The `Parameter` objects all implement a common interface and the *implementation of each subclass* will differ.

```
public CommandBuilder append(Parameter p) {
   // the append method called depends on the underlying type of 'p'
   p.append(this);
}
```

Comment: Cool. So something like this:
`public class URLParameter extends Parameter {

 @Override
 public void append(Command.CommandBuilder builder) {
  builder.append((URLParameter) this);
  
 }
}`

Comment: Looks not unreasonable. Your subclassing of CommandBuilder determines what to call on Parameter, and your Parameter subclass determines what happens when that's called (I always have to stop and really think about what's going on in these situations - it's not entirely intuitive!)

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that in the future, new parameters might have to be introduced. Is it still a good way of doing this then? Or is there a better way

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793720/how-to-make-this-builder-implementation-more-flexible-expandable

Comment: If you add new parameters you simply have to implement the associate dinterface. Because you're using method dispatch to determine what to call, everything should just work. You don't have to edit switch or if/else if clauses and consequently it all works rather well

Comment: So in your opinion. Its not too ulgy for having to create new `append(ConcreteParameter)` methods in de CommandBuilder  everytime you create a new ConcreteParameterClass?

Answer (score 4):

I would add a visitor method to your interface

```
interface Parameter {
    public void append(CommandBuilder builder);
}

class CommandBuilder {
    public CommandBuilder append(Parameter p) {
       p.append(this);
    }
}
```